# Vetor C++ imprimindo lixo

Tags: array, c++, números-binários

Salve pessoal. Tô construindo um simulador de cache em C++ pra um trabalho da faculdade. Enquanto construia e testava o código, me deparei com esse erro. A ideia era o usuário definir a quantidade de endereços da memória principal e o código converter de decimal para binário e imprimir, mas ele imprime junto o que acredito ser lixo de memória, a cada execução os números após os binários ficam aleatórios. Não sei como resolver. Se alguém me der uma luz agradeço

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int DecToBin(int n){
    // array para armazenar o binário
    int binaryNum[32];

    int i = 0;
    while (n > 0){
        //armazenando os restos das divisões da conversão
        binaryNum[i] = n % 2;
        n = n / 2;
        i++;
    }
 
    // imprimindo a array em ordem inversa
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--){
        cout << binaryNum[j];
    }
}

int main(){

    int Qtd_enderecos = 0;
    int  Qtd_bits = 0;
    //int mem_principal[Qtd_enderecos];
    //int mem_cache[Qtd_bits];

    cout << "Nota: os tamanhos devem ser em base 2;\n2, 4, 8, 16, 32..." << endl;
    cout << "Insira o tamanho da memoria principal: ";
    cin >> Qtd_enderecos;
    Qtd_bits = log2(Qtd_enderecos);
    cout <<"\n\n";

    cout << "Memória principal de " << Qtd_enderecos << " endereços" << endl;
    cout << "Memória cache de " << Qtd_bits << " endereços" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    // construção da array e memórias
    for (int a = 1; a <= Qtd_enderecos; a++){
        cout << "Posição " << a << " em binário: " << DecToBin(a) << endl;
        
    }
    
   
    return 0;
}
```

O output fica:

```
Nota: os tamanhos devem ser em base 2;
2, 4, 8, 16, 32...
Insira o tamanho da memoria principal: 8


Memória principal de 8 endereços
Memória cache de 3 endereços

Posição 1 em binário: 1-1970048960
Posição 2 em binário: 10-1970048960
Posição 3 em binário: 11-1970048960
Posição 4 em binário: 100-1970048960
Posição 5 em binário: 101-1970048960
Posição 6 em binário: 110-1970048960
Posição 7 em binário: 111-1970048960
Posição 8 em binário: 1000-1970048960
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Consegui solucionar o erro. Eu tava imprimindo a variável dentro de uma impressão em um loop for. Acredito que seja isso. Onde era

```
for (int a = 1; a <= Qtd_enderecos; a++){
        cout << "Posição " << a << " em binário: " << DecToBin(a) << endl;
        
    }
```

deixei como:

```
for (int a = 1; a <= Qtd_enderecos; a++){
        cout << "Posição " << a << " em binário: ";
        DecToBin(a);
        cout << endl;        
    }
```

Output agora:

```
Nota: os tamanhos devem ser em base 2;
2, 4, 8, 16, 32...
Insira o tamanho da memoria principal: 8
Memória principal de 8 endereços
Memória cache de 3 endereços
    
Posição 1 em binário: 1
Posição 2 em binário: 10
Posição 3 em binário: 11
Posição 4 em binário: 100
Posição 5 em binário: 101
Posição 6 em binário: 110
Posição 7 em binário: 111
Posição 8 em binário: 1000
```